# Java: Using textfiles

Tags: java, io

My main screen loads up as such:

> Press 1 to find Artist List
>
> Press 2 to Book Event
>
> Press 3 to Exit Program
>
> Menu 1: Artist List 2: Book Ticket 3: Exit Please select an option: 1
>   - 3

Option 1 brings up the list of artists I have stored on a text file which is fine. But option 2 is where the issue is as when I select option 2 it shows as such:

> Menu 1: Artist List 2: Book Ticket 3: Exit Please select an option: 1
>   - 3
>
> 2
>
> Prompt Message:  Please be advised that maximum tickets allowed to be
>   purchased is 6.
>
> Input Artist:  beyonce
>
> Number of Tickets required:  2
>
> Input Customer Details

My code is:

case 2: //to book the venue

```
    String chosenArtist = " ";


    int availability = 0;

    int capacity = 0;  //for the calculation of capacity that will be left

    //is the text file that customer details are stored too
        String file_name = "/Users/petercanning/Desktop/customerFile.txt";

    WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name, true);

    //the prompt message displays when option 2 is selected
    System.out.println("\n" + "Prompt Message: ");
    System.out.println("Please be advised that maximum tickets allowed to be purchased is 6." + "\n");

    //input the artist name
    System.out.println("\n" + "Input Artist: ");
    chosenArtist = sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();



    //error handling, if ticket is above or below number of tickets allowed
    while(numberTickets < 1 || numberTickets > 6){

    //input the number of tickets required
    System.out.println("\n" + "Number of Tickets required: ");
    numberTickets = sc.nextInt();

    if(numberTickets > 6)
    {
    //this error is displayed if the number of tickets selected is above 6
    System.out.println("Error: You have input the incorrect number of tickets allowed.");

    System.out.println("Number of Tickets required: ");
    numberTickets = sc.nextInt();
    }
    if(numberTickets < 1)
    {
    //this error is displayed if the number of tickets selected is below 1
    System.out.println("Error: You have input the incorrect number of tickets allowed.");

    System.out.println("Number of Tickets required: ");
    numberTickets = sc.nextInt();

    }

    }


    for (Artist A : artistList)

    //this is used to get the ticket price and times it by the number of tickets
    if (A.getArtist().equals(chosenArtist))
    {

    System.out.println("Total Price including fees: ��" + (A.getTicketPrice() * numberTickets + answer));
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Input Customer Details");

    //this is the input of customer details that will be saved to the customer file
    System.out.print("\n" + "First Name: ");
    firstName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("\n" + "Surname: ");
    secondName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("\n" + "Address: ");
    sc.nextLine();
    address = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n" + "Paymet Method: Visa/American Express/Mastercard");
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n" + "Card Number: ");
    cardNumber = sc.nextLong();
    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Payment Transaction complete ");

    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName + "\nSurname: " + secondName + "\nAddress: " + address);

    data.writeToFile(artistList + " " + numberTickets + " " + firstName + " " + secondName + " " + address);


    System.out.println("Payment Successful");

    System.out.println("Customer booking saved!");

    System.out.print("Which artist do you wish to update - Enter Artist");
    chosenArtist = sc.next();

    for(Artist A : artistList)
    {
    if(A.getArtist().equals(chosenArtist)){
    System.out.println("Artist " + chosenArtist + " found");

    availability = (A.getAvailability());

    capacity = 1;
    }
    }

    if(capacity == 0){
    System.out.println("The person does not exist");
    }


    break;
```

For some reason after I input the number of tickets, the program is ignoring the section where it's to add the number of tickets with the ticket price and I can't figure out why it does this and I also can't figure out how the update of the capacity isn't working either.

My artist text file also looks like:

> beyonce hydro 44.40 1200
>
> dan glasgow 23 120
>
> BonJovi SECC 82 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code isn't working...

```
for (Artist A : artistList)

//this is used to get the ticket price and times it by the number of tickets
if (A.getArtist().equals(chosenArtist))
{

System.out.println("Total Price including fees: ��" + (A.getTicketPrice() * numberTickets + answer));
}
```

Obviously your 'if' condition is not being met. I would say that your text file is somehow not correct, or whatever you are doing to parse the artist name from the text file is not parsing how you think it is.

Check your parser.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me if the '{' is missing in the for loop deliberately or is this an error?

Answer (score 0):

For what you say, it looks like your `artistList` is empty, but you should debug your program to make it sure.  If you have any problem with that, tell us what is your programming environment (command line, eclipse, etc.) and let's look for a solution for that.

Comment: I had it working before.  In college I'm using eclipse and have eclipse on this computer at home but eclipse is playing up, so I copied the project over to netbeans.  I'll show my full code and classes:

Comment: Do you know how to execute it step by step in netbeans?  It is your best option to know what is happening

Comment: not really.  I've been using eclipse for all of the project but the other day I updated eclipse and it has made most of my jar files missing.  Now when I've added new coding to my project its treating it as if the code isnt there.

Comment: @user3514608 Clean and rebuild your project in eclipse.